# Bootstrap: Add Button to list-group-items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I need to add multiple actions to list group items, all the Purple area needs to follow a link, and the Yellow area to open a Modal.

Currently the list group items are **anchors**, since is not valid HTML to nest anchors or buttons, I searching for another solution.

Any ideas?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Icon have id, so give id to input and use jQuery code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#simple').click(function(){
  window.onload = window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#basic-addo1').click(function(){
  window.onload = window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="simple">
</div>
```